# Bootstrap datepicker libraries loading order issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using SB Admin template for my application. I want to add bootstrap date picker to my input. But somehow I'm missing the order of JS & CSS libraries loading order which I think is not working in my case as going through multiple articles.

Below is code in `<html>` section

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="{{URL::asset('css/sb-admin-2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/lang/en-gb.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label" for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

it's a conflict with moment.js as i know.look if moment have his own datepicker library.

Comment: I have following link which may help https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Datetime-Picker-jQuery-Moment.html